# Does anyone make a small traditional-style suitcase without wheels?

Tags: hand-luggage

I'm looking for a soft-sided traditional suitcase that zips into two halves, without wheels. 16x12x10, or so. It's to fit into a trunk on a motorcycle for touring.

Comment: Try a search on "tail bag", should lead to some options.

Answer (score 3):

Many manufacturers do, calling them a boarding bag or carry-on. Without knowing your location (and, thus, sources), here are just a few that have global portals.

- [Samsonite Aspire](http://shop.samsonite.com/aspire-xlite/) boarding bag 16.5 x 12 x 10
- [Victorinox Werks Traveler](https://www.swissarmy.com/us/en/Products/Travel-Gear/Carry-On-Bags/c/TRG_CarryOn) 5.0 Weekender 18.5 12 8
- [Travelpro Maxlite](http://www.travelpro.com/collection.cfm?collection=MaxLite%204) 4 Soft Tote 15" x 11" x 8"
- [Pathfinder Revolution](http://www.pathfinderluggage.com/Product.aspx?PROD_CD=P3157-01-18TT) Plus Cabin Bag 18" x 11.5" x 10.5"
- [Tom Bihn Pilot](https://www.tombihn.com/collections/travel-bags) 15.4" x 11.4" x 5.1"

Alternatively, searches for 'pilot bag' and 'motorcycle luggage' return many additional options, and price ranges.